# Authentication over SSL using hash and salt

Tags: security, ssl, hash, bluetooth

I have researched this topic exhaustively and am stuck -- was hoping to get some clarification from helpful folks.

Background: I have Bluetooth transponders attached to locks that are opened by payment in my app.  A user pays a fixed fee, the lock opens, they grab their item, and the door closes and locks.  I am trying to prevent spoofing attacks where non paying users are able to open these locks.

My current solution theoretically goes as follows: Each transponder is given a random 32 bit salt.  Once the app Connects, an authentication request is sent to the transponder which creates A random challenge string + its unique salt.  The transponder then hash iterates the string 10,000 (to protect against brute force) times using SHA256. Meanwhile, the original challenge string+salt are transmitted to the app which then sends it to a secure server via SSL where the shared secret hash key and transponder salt are located.  The string is hash iterated 10,000 times using Sha256 , sent back to the app, and back to the transponder which validates the server hash against the its calculated hash.  If equal, the lock opens.

My questions are: is this secure?  Am I overlooking some glaring security flaw whether it be brute force or other? Am I just completely wrong? Any help or recommendations would be much appreciated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross-post of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131764/authentication-over-ssl-using-hash-and-salt.

Answer (score 0):

One potential thing to consider:

If you transmit the salt and the challenge string to the app and then on to the server, all of the information you need to generate the correct answer is available. The only secret bit is your hashing algorithm, but that is on stack overflow now.

To make life more difficult for people trying to compromise your system you do not need to send the salt in the communication. Instead, when you add a new transponder to the system, you add a transponder ID and its unique salt to a database that the server can access. Instead of sending the salt, you send the random challenge and the transponder id. The server then looks up the salt using the transponder id.

That way the salt is never transmitted and remains secret (as long as your servers are not compromised).

That has problems of its own. The salt can be reverse engineered from the transponder, as can the algorithm you use to generate the hash. It does make things more difficult though, particularly if you obfuscate and protect the salt on the transponder.

For completeness it is worth mentioning that you want to ensure that the traffic you send between all of the components are encrypted. Between the server and client app, this would mean using TLS. I know little about bluetooth, so I don't know what the standard method of encrypting the communications is. To further secure the communications between client and server over TLS, you might want to implement a form of [pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning).